# centering absolute div horizontally in relative table cell

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a table with table cells. In those table cells, i want to display an absolute positioned div. The div has a fixed top and bottom, and i want it to be displayed in the center of the table cell. Here is my code so far:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 30%;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Content</div>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>

</html>
```

I set margin to auto, hoping it would center the div, but it doesn't. Due to other requirements of how the page should look, i have to include table-layout in it and i cannot set the width of the td.

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The div has to be positioned absolutely?

Comment: If it is 90% wide, then why not simply center it by adding `left:5%` …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you gave the absolutely positioned element a width, you would just have to add `left: 0; right: 0;` in order to center it horizontally.

Alternatively, since the element has a fixed, percentage-based width of `90%`, you could also just use `left: 5%` to center it horizontally.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Content</div>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>

</html>
```